# I'm building a movie recommendation system based on genre, where the user will enter his choice and will receive recommendations based on his choice:

Tags: similarity

Column Name: "Genres" //This will contain the genres of movies
User genre: "Action Adventure"

I want to perform cosine similarity on this data, compare user genre with genres of different movies, sort and display the names of movies having similar genre. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your question is very general and missing crucial information - you should highlight which language and dataset you are planning to use. You should also include it in tags of the post.

Anyway, I suppose that you are working with one of the IMDB datasets. I can personally recommend [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-cosine-similarity-to-build-a-movie-recommendation-system-ae7f20842599) and [this article.](https://medium.com/@bkexcel2014/building-movie-recommender-systems-using-cosine-similarity-in-python-eff2d4e60d24) The authors explain the basic techniques how to build a recommender system in Python using scikit-learn library including cosine similarity.